# Noisy Frequency Estimation using Hilbert Transform

Tags: frequency, estimators

I'm looking for a way to estimate instantenous frequency with low time-variation. The following MATLAB function (save as `test_fest.m`) does this using the *Hilbert* transform on a single 10 Hz sine tone. Sample rate `f_s` is 1000 Hz.

```
function test_fest()
%TEST_FEST()  Test Frequency Estimation using Various Techniques.

fS = 1000;
f = [10]';                                  % Sine Wave Frequency
nFFT = fS;
x = sin(linspace(zeros(length(f),1), f*2*pi, fS));
X = hilbert(x,nFFT);

fE = diff(unwrap(angle(X))) * fS / (2*pi); % Frequency Estimate
eE = mean((fE/f-1).^2); % MSQ Error

plot(fE,'.');
title(sprintf('Hilbert Transform Instantaneous Frequency Estimation of Sine Wave f=%.2f Hz, f_S=%g Hz, Mean-Square Error:%.2g', f, fS, eE))
```

Output is shown here:

[image]

I, however, get a greater error, `2.3e-5`, than I expected. Is there something wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digital Hilbert transform is tricky to do since an ideal Hilbert transformer requires an FIR filter with an impulse response from -infinity to +infinity. Obviously that can't be done, so numerical problems are unavoidable. They tend to be worst at low frequencies so my guess is you'd see a smaller error at, say, 100 Hz. Andrew Duncan's paper "The Analytic Impulse" is thorough analysis of what the digital Hilbert transform can and can't do. See http://www.andrewduncan.ws/air/index.html

Some alternative methods of measuring frequency have been discussed here: [Is there an algorithm for finding a frequency without DFT or FFT?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1317/is-there-an-algorithm-for-finding-a-frequency-without-dft-or-fft)