# Using FFT to determine frequency

Tags: fft, fundamental-frequency

I'm pretty new to digital signal processing, my degree touched on it briefly, but it's interested me since.
I am trying to determine the fundamental frequency of a guitar note played into a mbed LPC1768.

I am currently reading the analog signal in and storing it as an array of floats, the data is currently sampled at 1000Hz for 1 second.

By plotting the values against 1-1000 (milliseconds) I can create this graph. This is a ~1 second snippet of an E String being played.
[image]

I was hoping someone could give me a few pointers on the best library to use to convert my 1D array into a form which would give me the frequencies involved in this converting this data from time-domain to frequency-domain.

I have seen some libraries but I can't figure out how to actually implement them due to a lack of examples.

Comment: The place to search for the code is Github, not here. You can easily find something like this: https://github.com/bejayoharen/guitartuner. It is also worth to note that for using FFT for guitar tuners is not a good idea since it is more natural to analyze the whole signal without windowing. You can read http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1317/is-there-an-algorithm-for-finding-a-frequency-without-dft-or-fft/1321#1321 for more details.

Comment: You question is also miss-titled.  The fundamental frequency is a pitch frequency.  FFTs are for spectral frequencies, which is not usually the same as musical pitch.

Comment: Fair enough on the title. And your link helped Thank you hotpaw2 and your suggestion has also helped me @NikolayShmyrev